# How to Call MVC web Controller from Xamarin Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

```
string apiUrl1 = string.Format(@"http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/test/Home/getdata?id=1");

public static string GetData(string url)
    {

        string Result = "";
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                Result = client.DownloadString(string.Format(@"" + url + ""));


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.Message;
            Result = "";
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

I am trying to get Data from my Published .Net MVC Web Project But i am getting Server Error "**The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**"

My MVC Controller Code is Here

```
public JsonResult getdata(int? id)
    {
        List<Items> dbItems = Items.getItemsData(id);

        return Json(dbItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you would probably be better suited using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) (you wouldn't have to specifically convert your response to JSON on your controller), you can try something like below.  As far as the server error, you would have to debug that server side.

```
  public class RestClient
  {  
    HttpClient client;
    private string RestUrl = "http://192.168.1.103/test/Home/";
    private static List<Items> _items = new List<Items>();

    public RestClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 9999999;
    }

    public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems(int? id)
    {            
         List<Item> items= new List<Item>();
         var uri = new Uri(RestUrl + "getdata?id=" + id);
         var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            items= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(content);
            _items.AddRange(items);
         }
         else
         {
            //do something
         }    

        return _items;
    }
 }
```